# Table Toast data is growth out of control

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, vacuum

We are using PostgreSQL version 11 in our production environment. And we are running out of disk space because of Postgres. When I check the table sizes in my DB with this query I saw that the file_table table is the biggest table. But the actual table size is only 1.9GB. On the other hand table's toast size is 739 GB. I try the `vacuum file_table` command but nothing happen. I'm afraid of trying the execute `vacuum full file_table` command because there is only 25% free disk space left on the device.

My query:

```
SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
, pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
, pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
, pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
FROM (
SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes 
FROM (
  SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
          , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
          , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
          , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
          , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
      FROM pg_class c
      LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE relkind = 'r'
  ) a
) a ORDER BY total_bytes DESC;
```

The output of the query:

```
   oid   |    table_schema    |              table_name              | row_estimate | total_bytes  | index_bytes | toast_bytes  | table_bytes |   total    |   index    |   toast    |   table    
---------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 6036951 | public             | file_table                           |   2.1147e+07 | 796532998144 |   950206464 | 793494487040 |  2088304640 | 742 GB     | 906 MB     | 739 GB     | 1992 MB
```

`df -h` output:

```
/dev/sdb2       1,8T  1,2T  465G  73% /
```

So what can I do the reclaim this disk space? And what could have caused the problem?

EDIT 1:

This is my table definition:

```
      Column       |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('file_table_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 file_id           | integer                        |           | not null |                                        | plain    |              | 
 phone_number_to   | character varying(255)         |           | not null |                                        | extended |              | 
 phone_number_from | character varying(255)         |           | not null |                                        | extended |              | 
 created_at        | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                        | plain    |              | 
 updated_at        | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                        | plain    |              | 
 mail_raw          | text                           |           |          |                                        | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "file_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "file_table_file_id_index" btree (file_id)
```

This is the `VACUUM VERBOSE file_table` output:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.file_table"
INFO:  "file_table": found 0 removable, 74725 nonremovable row versions in 935 out of 254847 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 2091352576
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 238334 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.01 s, system: 0.01 s, elapsed: 0.02 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_6036951"
INFO:  "pg_toast_6036951": found 0 removable, 3258092 nonremovable row versions in 813495 out of 96604072 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 2091352576
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 36229742 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 4.18 s, system: 0.76 s, elapsed: 4.97 s.
VACUUM
```

Row count of the table: `21167178`

Update:

We deleted the unnecessary data from the table. The row count of the table is `519340` now. But nothing happens. The TOAST usage is still the same. Does running vacuum on the table makes difference or do we need to do something else?

Comment: Can you post the table definition? That would give us a hint as to what columns are eligible for TOASTing.

Comment: Can you also post the output of `VACUUM VERBOSE file_table`? It should show that the TOAST table is being processed and provide some statistics.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that you have a lot of data stored in that table.  Is there a reason to believe that this is not the case?

Comment: @jjanes Actually when I talked to the dev team about this they said they were keeping raw mail data in the raw_mail column. So I think it might be the case.

Comment: @dwhitemv I edited my question and add the outputs of your wants.

Comment: You’ll need to run `VACUUM FULL` to recover the disk space from the table. There has to be enough space for both the current and new table temporarily. You can try running `SELECT SUM(pg_column_size(mail_raw)) FROM file_table` to get an (low) estimate of the size of the new TOAST table. But it is time to invest in more storage space.